# asp.net login testing with jmeter

Tags: asp.net, testing, authentication, jmeter, load-testing

I am a newbie in jmeter tool. I want to test login to an asp.net website. But I was not successful after 2 days of search through the internet.

I am listing below the steps that I followed:

1. Add an `HTTP Request Defaults`.
2. Add an `HTTP Cookie Manager`.
3. Add two `Regular Expression Extractor` for `EVENTVALIDATION` and `VIEWSTATE`.
4. Add HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier with `ASP.NET_SessionId` (checked the `Path Extension` and `Cache Session Id`).

   [image]
5. There are two pages, one is `Login Get Page` and another is `Login POST Page`. In Login Post Page, I've added the following parameters:

   - UserName : `realUser`
   - Password : `realPassword`
   - __VIEWSTATE : `name="__EVENTVALIDATION"  id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+?)"`

   [image]

   - __EVENTVALIDATION : `name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+?)"`

   [image]

   - LoginButton : `Log+In`
6. Add a `View Results Tree`.

I've explored the following links but not successful.

- [load-testing-aspnet-with-jmeter.html](http://blog.technicallyworks.com/2009/06/load-testing-aspnet-with-jmeter.html)
- [load-testing-aspnet-sites-with-jmeter.html](http://blog.technicallyworks.com/2009/06/load-testing-aspnet-sites-with-jmeter.html)
- [ASPNETViewState](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterTesting/ASPNETViewState)
- [Load Testing ASP.NET Web Applications using Jmeter](http://www.qadit.com/blog/?p=1684)

**Current Output:**

[image: Current Output]

What am I missing?
Any suggestion please.

**Update:**

Test plan tree structure:

[image: Test Plan Tree Structure]

**Login Details:**
[image]

**Login Request Tab:**
[image]

Comment: What are you getting instead of the expected result?

Comment: I am attaching the expected output as image

Comment: @Gavin: According to output image, The login is not successful, any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try recording with Jmeter Proxy Server:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Then add all elemnts you described to make what's needed dynamic, except for Http Url rewriting Modifier.

Comment: Okay, I will try according to your guideline... and give feedback here

Comment: my login is not successful after checking with jmeter proxy. jmeter proxy shows the `viewstate` and `eventvalidation` data while my test doesn't shows the real data...it is as my input value `${VIEWSTATE}` and `${EVENTVALIDATION} `. Is this a problem?

Comment: So it seems replacement of regexp didn't occur, can you show your Test plan Tree structure ? I would like to see where post-processor is located

Comment: yes, i resolved these problems. i've some mistake in regular expression. But still the login is not successful. I am attaching my test plan tree structure in my question.

Comment: Show login request tab in View Results tree, and show login sampler config

Comment: i've attached the login request tab but what is the login sampler config? Can you please clarify? btw, thanks for your time.

Comment: In the test plan tree click on Login And make a screen shot of the part that is right to tree qtructure, also is what you show the result of recording or running test plan ?

Comment: Because I see a 404 at first then the last screenshot shows working sample

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28860/discussion-between-sarwar026-and-pmd-ubik-ingenierie)

Comment: At last my problem is resolved. my mistake was to put some extra space in viewstate variable. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

We also had these kind of problems getting a login page to work in jmeter.
Eventually we got it to work. Important to note is:

- You have to create two HTTP request samplers for the login page, First one that uses the GET Method. So that the viewstate can be captured by the regular expression extractors, then a 2nd one that uses the POST method that does the login.
- Use firebug or any other capture tool to capture the Post of your login page, and make sure to add all the controls that post values. If you forget one parameter then your page will give an error. Also the empty ___VIEWSTATE parameter was required for us. See screenshot for our Post request
- For some pages we also had to add the parameter __VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED with an empty value

[image: screenshot of the login http post request]