# JMeter - Error in URL Redirection

Tags: jmeter

I was trying to issue a https request through jmeter and observed am getting Error Page response data for login page (Post Method).

login page url redirecting to different url (i.e. Application Home Page) but my login page redirect to the Error page.

And for Post req sampler i got error code 302 - Object moved to here.

Any help in resolving this issue would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Probable https server that does not give a certificate or certificate must specify clearly in jmeter

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I mapped "ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA" certificate.

Comment: any solution here, I'm facing similar issue. When I test my API on Postman or from UI client, it works fine, however when trying to run on Jmeter , I get Response code 308

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're not handling some dynamic authentication token which is required in the post data or in the HTTP header.

There is probably a dynamically generated auth token on the page of the form itself (or the HTTP header) which you need to use instead of a static value.

You can capture the dynamic value with a post processor regular expression and then pass it in to the next request with the updated value.

There is a JMeter webinar which also covers exactly this scenario and how to solve it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv7KqxaLZd8

**UPDATE 1:**
Sound like you're testing an asp.net application. They can be very finicky with JMeter. Check out these articles and other SO solutions:
[asp.net login testing with jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008413/asp-net-login-testing-with-jmeter)
http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterTesting/ASPNETViewState
[How to use JMeter for load testing ASP.net web applications implementing viewstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248712/how-to-use-jmeter-for-load-testing-asp-net-web-applications-implementing-viewsta)

Comment: authentication tokens are passed with using regular expression. (ViewState and EventValidation) but still i got same issue.

Comment: My TestPlan like 
Thread Group
 - HTTP Request Defaults
 - HTTP Cookie Manager
 - Reg Expression for - ViewState
 - Reg Expression for - eventValidation
 - Recording Controller
   -- Recorded Sampler (via proxy)
     1> Here it is I have login - post method sampler
     2> Home page sampler is bi-default disable mode @ time of recording.
 - View Result Tree
1> For post method sampler When set Auto Redirection option then got Error Code 302-Object moved to here.
2> If set Follow Redirects option then my sampler result get 200-OK but response redirects to the Error page url instead of home page.

Comment: You're going to have to compare a successful login with just your browser and what's happening with JMeter. There is probably something you're missing. You can use chrome network view in developer tools to see every request and then compare that what JMeter is doing.

Comment: I go through the posted links but still its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, jmeter didn't have support for redirects. It has been added on 5.5.

Refer: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65328